# Split a variable into other variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Hello awesome people on the internet! I need some help :)
I have a php rcon script, this script saves the result of the rcon to a variable named results, this is an example.

> results = Showing 2 tracked objective(s) for lluiscab:- rcon: 4 (rcon)- test: 5555 (test)

I want to set a variable like rcon to 4 and test to 5555.
I used explode and other thinks that I found on the web, but I can't make it work. Does someone know how to do it?

Edit: This variable changes, so, sometimes I can have rcon, test and coins and sometime only rcon

Comment: Sorry, your question is completely unclear. Please edit your question (there is an `edit` button...) and explain what data _exactly_ you currently have. Best is to dump the current variable, so that we can see its structure and content.

Comment: Show a sample of real input (real variable values), and a sample of desired output (desired variable(s) and values), please.

Comment: I said it -.-' I have $results = Showing 2 tracked objective(s) for lluiscab:- rcon: 4 (rcon)- test: 5555 (test) and I want $rcon = 4 and &test = 5555 or the same with an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for this.

```
preg_match('/rcon:\s*(\d+).*test:\s*(\d+)/', $line, $match);
$rcon = $match[1];
$test = $match[2];
```

`\d+` matches a sequence of numbers, and putting `()` around it makes it a capture group. `$match` contains the parts of the input line that were matched by the regular expression, and `$match[N]` contains the Nth capture group.

If you need to capture anything that looks like `word: number`, you can use `preg_match_all` and an associative array.

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+):\s*(\d+)/', $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$results = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $results[$match[1]] = intval($match[2]);
}
```

For the example input, this will create

```
$results = array(
    'rcon' => 4,
    'test' => 5555
);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/va1ygB)

Comment: The problem is, this variable changes, so, sometimes I can have rcon, test and coins and sometime only rcon

Comment: I've added a more general method that puts the results in an associative array.

Comment: $line is the variable to split no? I'm getting null values with this

Comment: @Barmar I think you forgot to close the parenthesis on the preg_match call.

Comment: @lluiscab I've fixed some errors in the `preg_match_all` code. I've tested it now and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I made some other mistakes while fixing it. Now it really works.